# Getting timedout during smtplib.SMTP(“smtp.gmail.com”, 587) in Python

Tags: python-3.x, smtp

The following code is working perfectly in another computer:

```
def send_email(user, pwd, recipient, subject, body):
#lb.send_email('AlirezaFedEx@gmail.com','P&ENLAMS','info@nka-it.com','Test','This is a test')

import smtplib
FROM = 'AlXXX@gmail.com'
TO = ['info@XXX.com'] # recipient if isinstance(recipient, list) else [recipient]
SUBJECT = 'Test'#subject
TEXT = 'This is a test' #body

# Prepare actual message
message = """From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(user, pwd)
    server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
    server.close()
    print('successfully sent the mail')
except Exception as err:
    print("failed to send mail:" + str(err))
```

When running the following part:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
```

it starts to freeze and eventually gives the following error:

*TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond*

I checked proxy of my browser and disabled proxy but still getting the error. Any advice please?

Answer (score 0):

are you using proxy? If so, please disable the proxy and try again. This should work properly if you have an active internet connection.